# Password protect a PDF file in Go-language

Tags: go, pdf

I have got a task to password protect **PDF** documents (PDF v4) afterwards. I know how to achieve this using Java language, Python or PHP.

But since I've learned some **Go-language** basics I am looking for a way to do this in Go. Any suggestions or maybe a code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [unipdf](https://github.com/unidoc/unipdf) See [this example](https://github.com/unidoc/unipdf-examples/blob/v3/security/pdf_protect.go).